# Upgrade ASP.NET webforms site from .net2 to .net4 | Accessing referenced DLL woes

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0

I have an asp.net2 WebForms project which worked fine, including referencing a dll compiled for .Net2.

Problem is that I have now recompiled the dll for .Net4 and have also 'upgraded' the VS2010 asp.net WebForms project to .Net4 and the asp.net WebForms application won't access the dll.

The first time the dll is called I get System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The new dll is accessed by other WinForms applications OK.

Whatever the problem is, VS2010 freezes and I need to use Task Manager to close it down.

I've searched and can't find anything that even remotely points to what the problem might be.

Comment: When I use Task Manager to close VS2010 I am getting this error in VS2010:
source file xxx does not belong to the project being debugged
Searching doesn't reveal this as a related issue but I'm not sure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the dll's protection system. In effect, the dll was corrupted.

It is disappointing that no error events were raised to indicate a read error rather than just returning null.